# Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number when use map

Tags: web3js, private-blockchain, bug

I am new to Solidity programming and writing smart contracts for one of the application. I test the contract on my private train:

```
contract Proof
{
    struct FileDetails
    {
        uint timestamp;
        string owner;  //owner name
    }

    mapping (string => FileDetails) files;

    event logFileAddedStatus(bool status, uint timestamp, string owner,string fileHash);

    function set(string owner, string fileHash)
    {
        if(files[fileHash].timestamp == 0)
        {
            files[fileHash] = FileDetails(block.timestamp, owner);
            logFileAddedStatus(true,block.timestamp, owner,fileHash);
        }else{
            logFileAddedStatus(false,block.timestamp, owner,fileHash);
        }
    }

    function get(string fileHash) returns (uint timestamp, string owner)
    {
        return (files[fileHash].timestamp,files[fileHash].owner);
    }
}
```

I used this function and mined.

```
>  proof.set.sendTransaction("bob","abcdefgh",{from:web3.eth.accounts[0]});
```

It seemed work well.
But when I tried the following:

```
>  proof.get.call("abcdefgh")
```

I got this following error:

```
Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number: 
    at L (bignumber.js:3:2876)
    at bignumber.js:3:8435
    at a (bignumber.js:3:389)
    at web3.js:1110:23
    at web3.js:1634:20
    at web3.js:826:16
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:825:12
    at web3.js:4080:18
```

So the question is how can you run the function in Web3 without running into this error?

thx!

Comment: You should be sure that the `proof.set` method did in fact add the entry you are trying to add.  you should always add a `revert()` call in your solidity contract after logging the file adding status.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer and your advice. As you said, `proof.set` didn't add the entry and I am trying to find out why.